# C# How to Format currency in Reportviewer with Commas and Decimals

Tags: c#, reportviewer

How do i format currency with Commas and Decimals in Reportviewer? in C# ? I have been looking up and i have not seen something that does make some sense here

I have a Field called balance now i want to do something like this

```
=Format(CDec(balance.Value),"N")
```

I want to have something like this : `1,23456.00` Very new to this.

Answer (score 2):

In the design view. Right click in the field. Click on the properties. A new window will popup. There pick number on left side and do your formatting.

[image: Step one]

[image: Step two]

Comment: Sorry it doesnt open

Comment: @TimTim What is not opening?

Comment: initially the screenshot didnt Open. but it does now. I did as you have asked and it didnt Change.

Comment: @TimTim I dont know what to tell you. This is from my code. I just took screenshot of it. It works for me.

Comment: still shows as String thats what i mean and nothing Else. it shows like this 12345 and not like this 1,2345.00

Answer (score 1):

```
=FormatCurrency(balance.Value, "en-US", 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it's usually easiest if you cast/format the data in the SQL Query for the ReportViewer.

`SELECT FORMAT(Balance, 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Balance'` (where `Balance` is your column or value)

Note that if your column or value is a VARCHAR then you'll need to `CAST` it to a float first:

`SELECT FORMAT(CAST(Balance AS float), 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Balance'`

Comment: yes the column is VARCHAR asides using the SQL query , any other way to cast VARCHAR to show information of that sort.